# $\int_{0}^{a} \sin ^{\nu-2}(a-x) \sin (\nu x) d x=\frac{1}{\nu-1} \sin ^{\nu} a$

Tags: definite-integrals, complex-numbers, trigonometric-integrals

Prove that

> $$I=\int_{0}^{a} \sin ^{\nu-2}(a-x) \sin (\nu x) d x=\frac{1}{\nu-1} \sin ^{\nu} a$$ if $a>0, \operatorname{Re}(\nu)>1$

Attempt:
Using the property $\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx=\int_{0}^{a}f(a-x)dx$ we get
$$I=\int_{0}^{a}\sin^{\nu-2}(x)\sin(\nu a-\nu x)\:dx$$
$\implies$
$$I=\sin(\nu a)\int_{0}^{a}\sin^{\nu -2}(x)\cos(\nu x)\:dx-\cos(\nu a)\int_{0}^{a}\sin^{\nu -2}(x)\sin(\nu x)dx$$
$\implies$
$$I=\sin(\nu a)I_1-\cos(\nu a)I_2$$
Where $$I_1=\int_{0}^{a}\sin^{\nu -2}(x)\cos(\nu x)\:dx$$ and
$$I_2=\int_{0}^{a}\sin^{\nu-2}(x)\sin(\nu x)\:dx$$
Now we have:
$$I_1+iI_2=\int_{0}^{a}\sin^{\nu -2}(x)e^{i\nu x}dx$$
Any way to proceed from here?

Comment: Left hand side could be considered as a convolution, but it looks a dead end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
&\small\int_0^a\sin^{n-2}(a-x)\sin(nx)dx=\int_0^a\sin^{n-2}(t)\sin(n(a-t))dt\\
&\small=\int_0^a\left[\frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i}\right]^{n-2}\left[\frac{e^{in(a-t)}-e^{-in(a-t)}}{2i}\right]dt\\
&\small=\frac1{(2i)^{n-1}}\int_0^a \left[e^{it(n-2)}\left(1-e^{-2it}\right)^{n-2}\right]
\left[e^{in(a-t)}-e^{-in(a-t)}\right]dt\\
&\small=\frac1{(2i)^{n-1}}\int_0^a \left[e^{it(n-2)}\sum_{k\ge0}(-1)^k\binom{n-2}{k}e^{-2itk}\right]
\left[e^{in(a-t)}-e^{-in(a-t)}\right]dt\\
&\small=\frac1{(2i)^{n-1}}\sum_{k\ge0}(-1)^k\binom{n-2}{k}\left\{e^{ina}\int_0^ae^{-2it(k+1)}dt-e^{-ina}\int_0^ae^{2it(n-k-1)}dt\right\}\\
&\small=\frac1{(2i)^{n-1}}\sum_{k\ge0}(-1)^k\binom{n-2}{k}\left\{e^{ina}\left[\frac{e^{-2it(k+1)}}{-2i(k+1)}\right]_0^a-e^{-ina}\left[\frac{e^{2it(n-k-1)}}{2i(n-k-1)}\right]_0^a\right\}\\
&\small=\frac{-1}{(2i)^{n}}\sum_{k\ge0}(-1)^k\binom{n-2}{k}\left\{e^{ina}\frac{e^{-2ia(k+1)}-1}{k+1}+e^{-ina}\frac{e^{2ia(n-k-1)}-1}{n-k-1}\right\}\\
&\small=\frac{-1}{(2i)^{n}}\sum_{k\ge0}(-1)^k\binom{n-2}{k}\left\{
\frac{n\, e^{ia(n-2k-2)}}{(k+1)(n-k-1)}-\frac{e^{ina}}{k+1}-\frac{e^{-ina}}{n-k-1}\right\}\\
&\small=\frac{1}{(2i)^{n}}\left\{\frac{e^{ina}}{n-1}\sum_{k\ge0}(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n}{k+1}e^{-2ia(k+1)}+\sum_{k\ge0}(-1)^k\binom{n-2}k\left[\frac{e^{ina}}{k+1}+\frac{e^{-ina}}{n-k-1}\right]\right\}\\
&\small\stackrel{(*)}=\frac{1}{(2i)^{n}}\left[\frac{(e^{ia}-e^{-ia})^n-e^{ina}}{n-1}+\frac{e^{ina}}{n-1}\right]\\
&\small=\frac{\sin^n a}{n-1},
\end{align}$$
where in $(*)$ we used:
$$\begin{align}
&\small\sum_{k\ge0}(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n}{k+1}e^{-2ia(k+1)}=\left(1-e^{-2ia}\right)^n-1\\
&\small\sum_{k\ge0}(-1)^k\binom{n-2}k\frac1{k+1}=\frac{-1}{n-1}\sum_{k\ge0}(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n-1}{k+1}=\frac{1}{n-1},\\
&\small\sum_{k\ge0}(-1)^k\binom{n-2}k\frac1{n-k-1}=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{k\ge0}(-1)^{k}\binom{n-1}{k}=0.
\end{align}$$

Comment: He defines $\nu$ as a complex number not as an integer.

Comment: @DINEDINE I never stated that $n$ is integer. To reassure you: in my derivation it is assumed that $n\in\mathbb C$ with the real part larger than $1$.

Comment: Okay. Did not know about this generalized binomial theorem.

Comment: **I have doubts with this proof** : on line n°4, you use the "generalized binomial theorem" which is the expansion of $(1+z)^{\alpha}$ but its validity is asserted on the open disk $|z|<1$. What proves convergence on the circle $|z|=1$ with $z=e^{-2it}$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for the nice question! [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) you find a proof that the series $(1+z)^\alpha$ converges for all $|z|=1$ if $\Re(\alpha)>0$ and for all $|z|=1$ except for $z=-1$ if $-1<\Re(\alpha)\le 0$ (conditions iii and iv). This means that our series converges everywhere if $\Re(n)>2$. If $1<\Re(n)\le 2$ the series diverges at single point $t=0$. This divergence on a set of measure $0$  however does not matter in view of subsequent integration.

Comment: @user Very interesting and nice answer. I didn't know this rather exceptional property of generalized binomial expansion ; I remember having seen very fine analysis results giving conditions under which a point lying on circle $|z|=R$ is a point of convergence...